# How do I get a pathname in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, path, directory, absolute-path

I'm working on an internal web app and I need to get a directory path from the user. I (obviously) can use the asp:FileUpload to get a file but I can't find anything to just get a directory path.

Is there any (preferably simple) way to have a directory-chooser dialog in asp.net? I haven't been able to find any solution on Google or SO yet...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are working on a web app, you are "stuck" with the limitations of what is allowed by the browsers.  And I do not believe any of the browsers include a "directory-chooser".

You will probably just have to ask the user to paste the path into a textbox.  You can then use some System.IO methods to verify the path is valid when the page is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try basic HTML `<input type="file">` ??? Or does this not serve your purpose?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - it's limited to opening a file(name). There's no option for selecting a directory. There are some hacks based off that input, but none of them are really that good.